# Does Berkeley DB support row-based storage or column-based storage?

Tags: berkeley-db

I read some Berkeley DB documentations recently, I know that the data is stored as the format of key-value. But I am still wondering, does Berkeley DB support row-based storage or column-based storage?

Comment: Wiredtiger does support row based storage AND column based storage but not berkeley db.